# Need help querying a max value from duplicated data, grouped by multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-update, inner-join, having-clause

I have data with lots of duplicates, and I am trying to update only the rows where the quantity is the highest, grouping by multiple columns.  I tried this but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
UPDATE `polls` AS `p1`
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT *
   FROM `polls`
   GROUP BY `server_id`, `product_id`, `poll_date`
   ORDER BY max(quantity)
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS `p2`
   ON `p2`.`server_id` = `p1`.`server_id`
   AND `p2`.`product_id` = `p1`.`product_id`
   AND `p2`.`poll_date` = `p1`.`poll_date`
   SET `p1`.`updated_by` = 'admin';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 ....
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT * , max(quantity)
   FROM `polls`
   GROUP BY `server_id`, `product_id`
   ORDER BY max(quantity) desc 
 )
 ....
```

Comment: that didn't work, It only got the highest quantity out of the whole set. I want the highest quantity from each set of duplicates.

Comment: the query was running for over an hour, so i stopped it. no luck :(

Comment: better show your sample data or fiddle if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
use this
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT *
   FROM 'polls'
   GROUP BY `server_id`, `product_id`, `poll_date`
   ORDER BY quantity desc limit 1
 )
```